# What are known approaches to graphing algebraic expressions?

Tags: javascript, parsing, shunting-yard

I am planning to build an expression parser that will be used to graph algebraic functions ( think TI-83 ) with JavaScript.

Functions will take the form of `f(x)=`

Aside from typical operators such as: `+ - * / ^`

I'd also like to add support for inline functions such as: `sin()`, `cos()`, `log()` and `random()`.

I have looked at implementing the Shunting Yard algorithm for parsing expressions, but it does not look like an efficient approach to evaluating a function with a hundreds or thousands of inputs. What other known algorithms exist for this task?

Comment: Shunting Yard is for parsing. Why would you run it more than once for a given function definition?

Comment: I might be thinking about this wrong, but it seems that I would need to run the algorithm for each value of x.

Comment: Is it possible that you evaluate the function directly while running shunting yard, instead of building a simpler representation (such as Reverse Polish Notation - RPN for short) of the function, as it's intended?

Comment: The Wikipedia article has a link to another algorithm: [Operator-precedence parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser)

Answer (score 1):

Shunting Yard is O(n) on the length of the function.  You can't get any better asymptotic complexity than that, so you're left with potential linear speedup.  The only thing I can think of that *might* be faster is to translate the function into native javascript and use `eval`.  You definitely want to benchmark that, though.  Another thing to do would be to only generate the RPN version once, then just execute that for each value of `x`.